# PHP Firebase Notification Fail for IOS

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a push notification script in PHP.  This script returns a successful result, however, the IOS device does not display the notification.

I have used Firebase Console to test notification. The notifications are successfully displayed on IOS devices.

My PHP code:

```
$msg = array
(
    'body'  => "test",
    'title'     => "test",
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
);

 sendGoogleCloudMessage( $msg, $ids );

function sendGoogleCloudMessage( $data, $ids )
{
    // Insert real GCM API key from Google APIs Console
    // https://code.google.com/apis/console/        

  define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'my API TOKEN' );

    // Define URL to GCM endpoint

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $post = array(
                    'to'  => '/topics/mytopic',  
                    'notification' => $data,               
                    );


    // Set CURL request headers (authentication and type)       
    $headers = array( 
                        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );

    // Initialize curl handle       
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set URL to GCM endpoint      
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    // Set request method to POST       
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

    // Set our custom headers       
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

    // Get the response back as string instead of printing it       
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    // Set JSON post data
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $post ) );

    // Actually send the push   
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    // Error handling
    if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
    {
        echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
    }

    // Close curl handle
    curl_close( $ch );

    // Debug GCM response       
    echo $result;
}
```

Result: **`{"message_id":9138025304879801378}`**

I am not sure what the problem is but I have tried different scripts too but even it shows a successful result, it does not display in IOS device.

Comment: Have you checked the application has notification permissions & is subscribed to the topic you're posting to? (sorry, had to ask!)

Comment: Hi JakeSteam,
The application displays the notification when I test it from Google Firebase Console.